# Cyclic Multiplication in S3, how do I do it?

Tags: group-theory

There's a simple fact stated in my textbook.

If H is the subgroup of S3 defined by the permutations {(1),(123),(132)}, then:

(1)H=(123)H=(132)H={(1),(123),(132)}
(12)H=(13)H=(23)H={(12),(13),(23)}

H(1)=H(123)=H(132)={(1),(123),(132)}
H(12)=H(13)=H(23)={(12),(13),(23)}

I don't understand how they got these numbers! I thought that for cyclic multiplication, the second set should dictate the order of the elements in the first.
So
(123)(123)=(123)
(213)(321)=(312)
etc.

and if there is a missing element, I thought that the rest should disappear, so

(123)(1)=(1)
(321)(12)=(32)

So, for example, if I tried to multiply the groups in the question,
H(12)={(1),(123),(132)}(12), this should equal {(1),(12),(13)}

But one of the results is supposed to be (23). I can't understand where this comes from.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of cycles as functions and apply them to each element of the domain to find out what the resulting permutation is.  Consider 
$$  (123)(123)  $$
Using square brackets to indicate evaluating as a function, this is \begin{align*}
(123)[(123)[1]] &= (123)[2] = 3  \\
(123)[(123)[2]] &= (123)[3] = 1  \\
(123)[(123)[3]] &= (123)[1] = 2
\end{align*}
The result is that $(123)(123)$ takes $1$ to $3$, $2$ to $1$, and $3$ to $2$.  So the product is $(123)(123) = (132)$.

One frequently starts by doing this out loud and saying what each cycle does.  For instance, for $(123)(12)$:

- $1$ is taken to $2$ by $(12)$, which is taken to $3$ by $(123)$.
- $2$ is taken to $1$ by $(12)$, which is taken to $2$ by $(123)$.
- $3$ is taken to $3$ by $(12)$, which is taken to $1$ by $(123)$.

So the result is $(13)$ (or $(13)(2)$, if you choose to write $1$-cycles).

Some people choose to follow one element around its result cycle.  This would give the order:

- $1$ is taken to $2$ by $(12)$, which is taken to $3$ by $(123)$.
- Then that $3$ is taken to $3$ by $(12)$, which is taken back to $1$ by $(123)$.  This gives the result cycle $(13)$.
- $2$ is taken to $1$ by $(12)$, which is taken to $2$ by $(123)$.  This gives the result cycle $(2)$.

Of course, we get the same product, but it can be easier to write it down one cycle at a time.  If working in $S_n$ for large $n$, it can be tricky to remember which of $1, \dots, n$ you haven't pushed through the product yet, so double-check that you haven't missed a cycle in the result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking about it all wrong!

Answer (score 1):

$S_3$ is the group of functions that map the set $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself.

$(123)$ is cylilc notation  of the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 2& x = 1\\3& x=2\\1&x=3\end{cases}$

Cyclic notation:

The first number after the open parenthesis maps to the number number that follows it.  The last number before the closed parenthesis maps to the first number in the cycle.

So,

$(132)$ is cylilc notation  of the function $g(x) = \begin{cases} 3& x = 1\\1& x=2\\2&x=3\end{cases}$

If a number is not represented, it maps to itself.

$(12)$ is $h(x) = \begin{cases} 2& x = 1\\1& x=2\\3&x=3\end{cases}$

putting two cycles next to each other is function composition.

$(12)(123)$ is the composition of the two, i.e. $h\circ f(x)$

$(12)H$ is the coset...  The set of all functions when $(12)$ is composed with each member of H.

i.e. $\{(12)(),(12)(123),(12)(132)\} = \{(12),(23),(13)\}$

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that $(132)(12) = (23)$. (The product is computed as follows: $1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 1$; $2 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 3$; $3 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 2$.)